# What Wireless G PCI Cards Are Compatible With Vista 64-bit?

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, wireless-networking

I'm looking to buy a PCI wireless interface card for a Vista Home Premium 64-bit machine.

I'm concerned about potential driver issues and am unable to determine what cards *don't* have driver issues.

- What PCI wireless cards are known to have (reasonably) stable and workable 64-bit drivers?
- What PCI wireless card would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

From Tom's Hardware : [List of Vista Supported Hardware & Software](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/page-232602_34_0.html)

Broadcom® bcm43xx Wireless (32 bits & 64 bits)
Gigabyte® Super G PCI Adapter (GN-WP01GT) (64 bit)
Intel® PRO/1000 PM Network connection (32 Bit & 64 Bit)
Linksys® Wireless-G PCI Adapter (WMP54G) (32 Bit & 64 bit)
Marvell Yukon® 88E8001/8003/8010 PCI Gigabit Ethernet Controller (32 Bit & 64 Bit)
Nvidia® nForce4 Network card - Version: 5.04, (64 Bit)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much anything that is from within the past year.

I had a lot of compatibility issues in the early days, but that is pretty much behind them.

I would recommend anything with a Realtek chip in them. The default driver in the box and Windows update sucks - either fails to connect or connects and doesn't work. Updating the driver to the latest from their site makes the card work flawlessly.

Realtek chips can be on any card and without looking, it is hard to tell. If you look on eBay for people who have posted pictures, you can probably tell. Brand is not that important as most people work from the same reference design, so even if you only spend £7 on a card, it should do the job.